# When a button is pressed go to a website link. How?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do you make it then when the button is pressed it goes to a website
Written in: Python + Tkinter

```
#The Button
button = tk.button(bg="orange", font=7, text="Visit Website")
visitWebsite.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)
```

Comment: Python has a standard module called `webbrowser` for opening a page in the user's browser - check it out.  If you were hoping to display the page inside your Tkinter application, that's not practical.

Comment: I know its not practical I just wanted to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the webbrowser module:

```
import webbrowser
url = 'https://sitename.com'
#The Button
visitWebsite = tk.button(bg="orange", font=7, text="Visit Website" command=lambda: webbrowser.open(url))
visitWebsite.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)
```